# htaccess - Rewriting requests for subdomain to a folder, with query string

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a subdomain rewrite working using an Apache htaccess file and need some help please.

I am trying to get requests for *http://**xyz**.example.com* internally handled *as if* the user had requested *http://example.com/**xyz*** so the user does not see this URL in their address bar - they see the subdomain version.

This is slightly complicated by the fact that anything following this *also* needs to be passed too, for example if the user requests *http://**xyz**.example.com/test/word/?x=123* then this needs to be handled by the server as if they had visited *http://example.com/**xyz**/test/word/?x=123*.

The site is running on the Code Igniter framework, which had its own htaccess rules too, but I guess this rewrite would be done first before those kick in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `[QSA]` to pass through GET parameters

Comment: Is Codeigniter in the site root, or in `xyz`?

Comment: Hi Tim - Code igniter is in the site root http://example.com. I have a subdomain created with an A record that points to the same IP as this root domain

Comment: Hi Pekka - that sounds like what I need, but I'm not sure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

The following [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule set should perform the rewriting you need:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php/)?xyz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.
RewriteRule ^.*$ /xyz/$0 [L]
```

The query string gets passed along automatically, since we haven't changed it in the rewrite.

For CodeIgnitor to pick this change up though, you'll need to be using `PATH_INFO` as the source of the routing information. Your `$config['uri_protocol']` needs to be set to `PATH_INFO` or `AUTO` for this to be the case, and your CodeIgnitor `RewriteRule` should look something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php/$0
```

If you run into trouble trying to use `PATH_INFO`, you'll need to find a way to get CodeIgnitor to parse `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` (and add the `L` flag to the first `RewriteRule` up there). Hopefully this shouldn't be necessary, but if you can't get it to work otherwise I'll look into how you might do that.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for looking into this. However strangely I get a 403 forbidden error, despite having PATH_INFO set. In the error_log it says "File name too long: Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file". The CI RewriteRule did look slightly different, but even after changing that to yours it still wouldn't work. The good news is that in the meantime one of my colleagues has also been experimenting with it - we've both been trying to get it to work! - and has now managed to make it work using RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.example\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/xyz/$1 [P] Thanks

Comment: @GSA - Ah yeah, that's because I failed to consider what happens after the CodeIgnitor rewrite. For completeness, I've updated the answer to fix that scenario. Your colleague's solution of using the `P` flag is fine too; I had just avoided suggesting that because it has the overhead of creating a brand new request as part of the proxy. Admittedly that's a non-issue if your server isn't under strain though.